# VB.NET missing special characters in string

Tags: vb.net, parsing, code-behind, indexof

I am sorry if I broke the cardinal rule of repeating a question. I have searched but had no luck. I am working on a remote computer through a VPN.

I have a text box in which I swipe a card and the contents populate.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCCard" runat="server" />
```

There are currently no functions running at this point. For some strange reason the text box is changing special characters to it's corresponding key on the keyboard.

Example is the **%** is being changed to a **5** and the **^** is being changed to a **6** and the **?** is being changed to **/**

Here is the card strip in Notepad
**%B5581588589815463^Doe/John^19031011516100806000000?;5581588589815463=190310115161806?**

Notice the special characters throughout the string.

This is what I get when I swipe it into the text field with no functions.

**5B55815885898154636Doe/John619031011516100806000000/;5581588589815463=190310115161806/**

All the characters are showing up as if you were clicking shift key on the keyboard. I hope this is a better explanation of my issue.

Comment: What have you tried so far to validate the string handling? What research have you done to see how strings with special characters are handled in ASP?

Comment: VB.Net does nothing different than Notepad when it receives keyboard input (which is what your scan is providing). If Notepad shows that content on a single line, then a TextBox will show it the same way - it does not parse content differently by itself.. And the single line of code you've put in your post does nothing that would change things (in fact, it's totally irrelevant and meaningless).

Comment: Try debugging and stepping through the program at this point. See what the string value is at each line of code. This will help you narrow down where the culprit is and you can then edit your question with specific (useful) code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to delete this question but I think someone else would benefit from the answer.

I work remotely which requires me to work over a remote connection. After researching and asking the right question Remote Desktop has a bug where it reads slowly and may characters can be changed or jumbled up.

To fix this follow the below steps.

1. Open Remote Desktop Dialogue
2. Click Show Options at bottom left
3. Click Local Resources Tab
4. Under Apply Windows Key Combinations. Select On this computer

Thank you for everyone's help.